# Run time error 91 object error object variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, refresh, worksheet

run time error 91 ....coding to refresh pivot table on sheet2 when data change in cell d3 in sheet1 and press enter.

Sometimes it work for some time after close and reopen excel file

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Sheet1.Range("D3")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
          Is Nothing Then
          Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

          Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.REFRESH BackgroundQuery:=False
          Sheets("Sheet1").Select
          Range("F3").Select
    End If

End Sub

Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.REFRESH BackgroundQuery:=False
```

error in this line while executing debugger....error 91...about object variable

Comment: Don't use `Selection`. You can refer to the `ListObject` by its name.

Comment: To BigBen ...still not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the revised code you're using, and explain in detail what is not working, thanks!